# TextInput texto en mayusculas - react native

Tags: react-native

Tengo un TextInput que me convierte lo que escribo en mayúsculas y funciona bien si lo pruebo en en el emulador o algún programa para probar código de react-native, pero al generar la apk para probarlo en el celular presenta el siguiente inconveniente: al intentar agregar un espacio mientras escribo no me deja.

code funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-sh4ir9?file=/src/App.js:0-1085

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";
//import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholderTextColor="gray"
        value={name}
        onKeyPress={(event) => {
          const { key } = event.nativeEvent;
          switch (key) {
            case "Backspace":
              setName((current) => current.slice(0, -1));
              break;
            default:
              setName((current) => `${current}${key.toUpperCase()}`);
          }
        }}
        selectionColor="orange"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        selectTextOnFocus={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    // paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    padding: 8
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
});
```